# How to pause/resume video recording using CameraX VideoCapture

Tags: android, camera, android-camerax, video-recording

I couldn't find any resume() or pause() function to pause/resume video recording in my Android app. Any help would be appreciated. There is stopRecording() function only that I used to stop and save the video recording as given below.

`videoCapture.stopRecording()`

How to pause video recording, so that users can continue from they left with ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the new `androidx.camera.video.VideCapture` not the deprecated `androidx.camera.VideCapture`, the APIs are:

- pause: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/video/Recording#pause()
- resume: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/video/Recording#resume()